# NativeScript JS: Missing Image with resourceID - Remote Image API

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

i'm make a little application in nativescript with angular, i consume a test api with a service.ts

```
getItems(){
    return this.http.get('https://apiexample.com/url');
  }
```

and it returns json with several images, but when I use this example and put directly the url

```
<image
  src="https://art.nativescript.org/logo/export/NativeScript_Logo_Blue_White.png"
  stretch="aspectFill"
>
</image>
```

the image shows

but when i use like this

```
<GridLayout>
  
  <ListView [items]="items">
    <ng-template let-item="item">
      <StackLayout>
        <image
  [src]="item.img_src"
  stretch="aspectFill"
  loadMode="async"
>
</image>
         <Label [text]="item.id"></Label>      
      </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
  </ListView>
</GridLayout>
```

If I put the code like that, it doesn't show me anything anymore. but on the console it tells me **JS: Missing Image with resourceID**
Any ideas? TY

[image]

Comment: Try to using ssl sertificate (https)